# SASS (not SCSS) version of Bourbon Neat

Tags: css, import, sass, bourbon, neat

I am wondering if there is a SASS (not SCSS) version of Neat that I can download?  The official [website](http://neat.bourbon.io/) uses SCSS. Currently my entire existing app is using SASS, and I don't want to introduce another style format.

Or can I import external SCSS files into my existing SASS files?

**UPDATE:**

One thing I can do is convert SCSS into SASS by this:

```
sass-convert -R my_scss_dir --from scss --to sass
```

Comment: Yes. You are probably importing neat into a main.css file anyways. As long as you are importing them, you can mix and match SASS and SCSS files without a problem. Your compiler doesnt care

Answer (score 0):

To answer, there is not a SASS version of Neat. Mainly this is due to the fact that most folks are more comfortable using SCSS syntax over SASS.

That said, unless you are making a completely static site and running sass via the command line, I would recommend including Neat via some sort of toolchain based on your tech stack and not adding the static files. Here's a couple of helpful links.

- [Neat on RubyGems for use in ruby projects](https://rubygems.org/gems/neat)
- [Neat on NPM for use in node projects](https://rubygems.org/gems/neat)
- [An example Middleman project using the Neat gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/middleman-template)
- [An example Gulp project using the Neat package](https://github.com/thoughtbot/gulp-bourbon-neat-example)